# Int vs. IndexPath Troubles

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am writing a function to loop through all of the cells in a UITableViewController. Here is what I have so far:

```
var i = 0
while (i < tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)) {
    i += 1
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: i-1)
}
```

Everything loops correctly until I try to get the cell. It expects an input of type `IndexPath`, however I am passing in an Int. Whenever I force it as an IndexPath like so:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: i-1 as! IndexPath)
```

I get a warning saying that it will always fail/ always return nil. Is there a better way to do this, or am I just missing a crucial step. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

EDIT (A LITTLE MORE EXPLANATION): All the cells are custom classed cells, with a specific variable. I want to loop through all of the cells and get that value.

```
let visibleCells = tableView.visibleCells
for aCell in visibleCells {
    print(aCell.question?.text) <------- this is the value I want
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question but I can almost guarantee that your attempt to loop through all of the cells is the wrong thing to do. What is your actual goal with that loop?

Comment: Probably better to use `tableView.visibleCells` depending on your actual goal like rmaddy has just asked.

Comment: All the cells are custom classed cells, with a specific variable. I want to loop through all of the cells and get that value.

Comment: If you are trying to retrieve data in `UITableViewCell`s, then you will fail for any cells off-screen. `UITableViewCell`s are re-used so only the "data" in the visible cells is available - data in any cells of-screen has already been lost. You should retrieve data from your data source not the cells; if you are entering data in a cell then that needs to be stored to a data source as soon as editing is ended.

Answer (score 2):

You should create an `IndexPath` via code, like this:

```
let ndx = IndexPath(row:i, section: 0)
```

Or, to modify your code:

```
var i = 0
while (i < tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)) {
    i += 1
    let ndx = IndexPath(row:i-1, section: 0)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at:ndx)
}
```

Based on the later edit where you mention that you want the value of a text string on each row, I would suggest that the above is probably not the best way to approach this :) (I know others have already said this, but I didn't want to make assumptions about what you wanted to do unless you specifically stated what you wanted ...)

You are probably better off taking the same approach you take to populate the data for the table view cells via `cellForRowAt:` to get the question text than to loop through all the table rows, which would result in some issues for non-visible rows as others have indicated already.

If you have any issues with getting the data provided for `cellForRowAt:`, do share the code for the `cellForRowAt:` with us and I'm sure one of us can help you figure things out :)

Comment: Why use a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop? Why increment `i` before using the current value?

Comment: @rmaddy I am simply using the logic he provided since I assume he had some logic in mind, but I might be wrong :)

Comment: I think the OP is just beginning and doesn't really understand what he's doing. He needs to tell us his actual goal to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the information below has been said by others in the other answers and comments, but I wanted to put it all in one place:

We need to step back from the specifics of the question and ask what you are actually trying to do.

The `UITableView` method `cellForRow(at:)` will only return cells that are actually on-screen. If there is only room for 5 cells and you have to scroll to expose the rest, that method will return nil for all but the cells that are visible.

As others have suggested, if your goal is to loop through the cells that are on-screen the property `tableView.visibleCells` would be a better choice.

If your goal is to loop through all cells that exist in your data then you need to explain what you are trying to do.

As for your specific question, the `cellForRow(at:)` wants a parameter of type `IndexPath`. You can't simply cast an Int to IndexPath. That will fail. Instead, as @TaylorM said in their answer, you need to create an IndexPath. If your table view only has a single section then you can simply use

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)
```

(Assuming you fix your loop code so your indexes start at 0.)

It also does not make sense to use a while loop like that.

Instead of all of this, I suggest using:

```
let visibleCells = tableView.visibleCells
for aCell in visibleCells {
   //Do something with the cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)
```

You may need to adjust the section to fit your needs.

Check out the documentation for [`IndexPath`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/indexpath). Like most classes and structures, `IndexPath` has [initializers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html). If you need to create a new instance of any object, you'll most like use an initializer.

*also see the comment from @rmaddy:
"Unrelated to your question but I can almost guarantee that your attempt to loop through all of the cells is the wrong thing to do. What is your actual goal with that loop?"

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have figured it out using all of the help from you wonderful people.

In my case, I have a custom class with a variable that I want access to. I can do what Taylor M, Fahim, and Duncan C said: `let indexPath = IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)`

Then I can add `as! NumberTableViewCell` to the end, which allows me access to the values defined there. In the end, it looked like this:

```
var i = 0
while (i < tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)) {
    i += 1
    var cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: i-1, section: 0)) as! NumberTableViewCell
    print(cell.question.text!)
    }
```

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: This is simply wrong. You do not want to get data from cells. Cells only display data temporarily. You must have all of your data in your data model. Simply iterate over your data model, not the cells.

Comment: I agree with rmaddy. You should not save data in cells. Each time a cell scrolls off-screen it gets recycled and its data is lost. You should have a data model to hold the information that you display in your table view, and any input from the user. An array works fine for a table view with 1 section. An array of arrays works well for a sectioned table view.

Comment: This table view will only have about six cells at max, so I thought that this was the appropriate method. Thanks!